# Merging two different models in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to merge two Keras models into a single model and I am unable to accomplish this.

For example in the attached Figure, I would like to fetch the middle layer $A2$ of dimension 8, and use this as input to the layer $B1$ (of dimension 8 again) in Model $B$ and then combine both Model $A$ and Model $B$ as a single model.

I am using the functional module to create Model $A$ and Model $B$ independently.  How can I accomplish this task?

**Note**: $A1$ is the input layer to model $A$ and $B1$ is the input layer to model $B$.

[image: See Picture]

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-networks-ensemble-33f33bea7df3

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question and here is the code that builds on the above answer.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import plot_model

A1 = Input(shape=(30,),name='A1')
A2 = Dense(8, activation='relu',name='A2')(A1)
A3 = Dense(30, activation='relu',name='A3')(A2)

B2 = Dense(40, activation='relu',name='B2')(A2)
B3 = Dense(30, activation='relu',name='B3')(B2)

merged = Model(inputs=[A1],outputs=[A3,B3])
plot_model(merged,to_file='demo.png',show_shapes=True)
```

and here is the output structure that I wanted:

[image]

Comment: Notice that you are *not* merging two models (in the sense of keras Model) in the above, you're merging layers.

Answer (score 14):

In Keras there is a helpful way to define a model: using the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).  With functional API you can define a directed acyclic graphs of layers, which lets you build completely arbitrary architectures. Considering your example:

```
#A_data = np.zeros((1,30))
#A_labels = np.zeros((1,30))
#B_labels =np.zeros((1,30))

A1 = layers.Input(shape=(30,), name='A_input')
A2 = layers.Dense(8, activation='???')(A1)
A3 = layers.Dense(30, activation='???', name='A_output')(A2)


B2 = layers.Dense(40, activation='???')(A2)
B3 = layers.Dense(30, activation='???', name='B_output')(B2)

## define A
A = models.Model(inputs=A1, outputs=A3)

## define B
B = models.Model(inputs=A1, outputs=B3) 

B.compile(optimizer='??',
          loss={'B_output': '??'}
          )

B.fit({'A_input': A_data},
  {'B_output': B_labels},
  epochs=??, batch_size=??)
```

So, that's it! You can see the result by: `B.summary()`:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param    
A_input (InputLayer)         (None, 30)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 248     
______________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 40)                360       
_________________________________________________________________
B_output (Dense)             (None, 30)                1230
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think the above code will work. First, when you say B = models.Model(inputs=A2, outputs=B3) it will give you an error TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs: Tensor. Also, as mentioned earlier, I did use functional API to create Model A and Model B separately. I think the answer I am looking for might have to do with the section "Multi-input and multi-output models" in keras documentation that uses concatenate function (not entire sure though).

Comment: @Rkz : I have edited the answer. It works now. We have to use "concatenate". Actually, you should mention the main input (A1)  when you want to define model "B".

Comment: Thanks for your time and edits. I figured out the answer from the Keras documentation (see the following answer). I did not require concatenate for my question.

Comment: @Rkz : Look at the final edit, I also show how to compile and fit the model.

Comment: hello, can you help me with -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68330534/merge-multiple-models-in-keras-tensorflow  \