# How to implement a cascaded neural network in Keras where 1st NN's forward output is cloned twice to perform forward on the 2nd NN?

Tags: neural-network, keras, backpropagation

Using Keras, I am trying to reproduce a few basic results from a published paper.

In this task, there are two neural networks - A & B, that are connected in a cascade formation, i.e. the output of model A feeds the input of model B. Please see the figure below.

[image: graphical description of cascaded neural network]

Here are the specifics steps that need to be implemented:

1. Perform one forward pass on model A with a batch size of 64, and 13155 rows.
2. Clone the output to create a batch of 128 rows i.e. use each training sample twice. (There are auxiliary inputs which distinguish the duplicate rows, but I have omitted that info for the sake of brevity).
3. Perform one forward pass on model B by feeding it with #2 above.
4. Now backward the two networks, calculate a loss for each one, sum the loss & send it to the optimizer with the gradients of both networks.

As I am quite new to the world of neural networks & Keras, I'd really appreciate any help from the community to implement the above steps in Keras. In particular, I am quite confused about implementing step 2 (please see the attached figure).

As a starting point, I had found [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26103/merging-two-different-models-in-keras) answer to be somewhat aligned to my question, but the details of customization to my specific problem is fuzzy, for example how to implement the forward & backward logic separately etc.

Comment: I am also interested in a solution to this question. Can someone from the community please point in a suitable direction?

Comment: Did you try to use Keras functional API? See here https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#manipulate-complex-graph-topologies

Comment: @VladislavGladkikh : Yes I did. But I am not sure how to clone prediction made by first network and by doing that double the batch size for training the second network?